# How to get the transaction id of a duplicate transaction in authorize.net?

Tags: authorize.net

Some time I get duplicate transaction error (error code 11) in authorize.net. How can I get to know the duplicate transaction id so that I can verify it. Or, is there any way to get the transaction id by sending the invoice number or any other parameters? I am using AIM wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Authorize.Net does not report the ID of the duplicate transaction. The best you can do is get a transaction history and look for a very recent transaction that contains the same payment information. You can use their reporting API and make a call to `getUnsettledTransactionListRequest`.